# Desktop text shadow

Tags: pixel, desktop, raspberry-pi-desktop

Is there a way to enable desktop text shadow in Raspbian’s DE (and specifically the pcmanfm which is being used to display desktop icons)?

I only managed to find [this](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=285306) solution which describes the way of achieving the desired effect but this guide is for Nemo Desktop.

If it is already enabled, I would like to know how to configure it to be more visible.

Comment: AFAIK the only setting in LXDE related to shadows is `desktop_shadow` which defines the shadow color. If you need more fancy settings, you'll have to use a different desktop environment.

Comment: I believe the default Raspbian desktop is now *The-DE-formerly-known-as-PIXEL*, as they aren't calling it anything anymore.   It is really a customized [LXDE](https://lxde.org/) (pcmanfm is an artifact of that), so you might be best off researching it that way.

Comment: @goldilocks thanks, I modified the question.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev quick googling shows the screenshots of lxde with text shadow enabled. In fact, there is an option “shadow color” in desktop settings. But **there is no shadow**

Comment: Unfortunately quick googling of LXDE's own site (`shadow "text shadow" site:https://lxde.org/`) doesn't turn up much (and that appears to include git repo sources, which is the only place where Dmitry's `desktop_shadow` shows up).  Some of the other stuff looks like it could be [XDG spec](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/), which most DE's implement to varying degrees.  Keep in mind that "shadow" in a DE context would most commonly refer to window shadows.